# css grid for gallery - selectors to repeat the 15 items - and - the grid stacks rather than flows beneath

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-grid

I am new to css grid and trying to put something together for a thumbnail photo gallery.

I made a grid (using a grid generator) with 8 columns and 12 rows and 15 (blame the graphic designer :)) items.

I am hoping to be able to repeat the 15 item pattern but have got myself totally confused with the selectors. And the 15 item grid stacks on top of itself which confuses me even more :).

The generator used a class for each item (eg .item1, .item2, .item3 etc) which I would like to avoid and instead replace with nth selector so that I don't have to keep adding the wrapper tag every 15 items (not sustainable in my CMS).

Wondering if someone can please help out?

As a bonus question: there will no doubt not be an even multiple of 15 photos each time (eg ending at the 4th grid in the html below)... is there a way to neaten off the final row of pics and fill the available space in the bottom row?

Extra question: is this kind of grid achievable in flexbox?

Many thanks and have a great day.

The css (i am presuming 15n+1 is way off the mark):

```
<style>

.grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr); grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr); /*grid-auto-flow: dense; */grid-column-gap: 20px; grid-row-gap: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; }

.grid .item { overflow: hidden; }

.grid .item img { width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+1) { 
grid-row-start: 1; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 5; grid-column-end: 5;
border: 1px solid red; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+2) { 
grid-row-start: 1; grid-column-start: 5; grid-row-end: 3; grid-column-end: 9;
border: 1px solid blue; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+3) { 
grid-row-start: 3; grid-column-start: 5; grid-row-end: 5; grid-column-end: 7;
border: 1px solid #03C; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+4) { 
grid-row-start: 3; grid-column-start: 7; grid-row-end: 5; grid-column-end: 9;
border: 1px solid green; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+5) { 
grid-row-start: 5; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 7; grid-column-end: 3;
border: 1px solid orange; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+6) { 
grid-row-start: 5; grid-column-start: 3; grid-row-end: 9; grid-column-end: 7;
border: 1px solid purple; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+7) { 
grid-row-start: 7; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 9; grid-column-end: 3;
border: 1px solid yellow; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+8) { 
grid-row-start: 5; grid-column-start: 7; grid-row-end: 9; grid-column-end: 9;
border: 1px solid #f0f; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+9) { 
grid-row-start: 9; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 11; grid-column-end: 4;
border: 1px solid grey; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+10) { 
grid-row-start: 9; grid-column-start: 6; grid-row-end: 11; grid-column-end: 9;
border: 1px solid tomato; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+11) { 
grid-row-start: 9; grid-column-start: 4; grid-row-end: 11; grid-column-end: 6;
border: 1px solid #0F0; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12) { 
grid-row-start: 11; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 13; grid-column-end: 3;
border: 1px solid #CF9; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+13) { 
grid-row-start: 11; grid-column-start: 3; grid-row-end: 13; grid-column-end: 5;
border: 1px solid #F39; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+14) { 
grid-row-start: 11; grid-column-start: 5; grid-row-end: 13; grid-column-end: 7;
border: 1px solid #93C; }

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+15) { 
grid-row-start: 11; grid-column-start: 7; grid-row-end: 13; grid-column-end: 9;
border: 1px solid #066; } 


@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {

.grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr); }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+1) { grid-row-start: 1; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 2; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+2) { grid-row-start: 1; grid-column-start: 2; grid-row-end: 2; grid-column-end: 3; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+3) { grid-row-start: 2; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 3; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+4) { grid-row-start: 2; grid-column-start: 2; grid-row-end: 3; grid-column-end: 3; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+5) { grid-row-start: 3; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 4; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+6) { grid-row-start: 3; grid-column-start: 2; grid-row-end: 4; grid-column-end: 3; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+7) { grid-row-start: 4; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 5; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+8) { grid-row-start: 4; grid-column-start: 2; grid-row-end: 5; grid-column-end: 3; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+9) { grid-row-start: 5; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 6; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+10) { grid-row-start: 5; grid-column-start: 2; grid-row-end: 6; grid-column-end: 3; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+11) { grid-row-start: 6; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 7; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12) { grid-row-start: 6; grid-column-start: 2; grid-row-end: 7; grid-column-end: 3; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+13) { grid-row-start: 7; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 8; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+14) { grid-row-start: 7; grid-column-start: 2; grid-row-end: 8; grid-column-end: 3; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+15) { grid-row-start: 8; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 9; grid-column-end: 3; } 

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.grid { grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr); grid-column-gap: 0; grid-row-gap: 20px; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+1) { grid-row-start: 1; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 2; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+2) { grid-row-start: 2; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 3; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+3) { grid-row-start: 3; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 4; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+4) { grid-row-start: 4; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 5; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+5) { grid-row-start: 5; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 6; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+6) { grid-row-start: 6; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 7; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+7) { grid-row-start: 7; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 8; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+8) { grid-row-start: 8; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 9; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+9) { grid-row-start: 9; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 10; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+10) { grid-row-start: 10; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 11; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+11) { grid-row-start: 11; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 12; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12) { grid-row-start: 12; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 13; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+13) { grid-row-start: 13; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 14; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+14) { grid-row-start: 14; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 15; grid-column-end: 2; }
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+15) { grid-row-start: 15; grid-column-start: 1; grid-row-end: 16; grid-column-end: 2; } 

}

</style>
```

The html (I think this is ok):

```
<div class="grid">

<!--1st grid-->
 <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 04</div>
 <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 08</div>
 <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 11</div>
 <!--4th row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 12</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 13</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 14</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 15</div>

<!--2nd grid-->
 <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">2 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 04</div>
 <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">2 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 08</div>
 <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">2 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 11</div>
 <!--4th row-->
  <div class="item">2 - 12</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 13</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 14</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 15</div>

<!--3rd grid-->
 <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">3 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 04</div>
 <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">3 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 08</div>
 <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">3 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 11</div>
 <!--4th row-->
  <div class="item">3 - 12</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 13</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 14</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 15</div>

<!--4th grid (incomplete)-->
 <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">4 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 04</div>
 <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">4 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 07</div>

</div>
```

Edit: showing the "column neatening" css per Temani's code (not sure if this is the right way to add)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {

/*adjustments to neaten columns if the final grid is incomplete (eg less than 15 images)*/

/* If 15 is missing, make 13 and 14 bigger */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+13):nth-last-child(2),
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+14):last-child {
     grid-column:span 3;
  }
/**/

/* If 14 is missing, make 12 and 13 bigger */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12):nth-last-child(2),
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+13):last-child {
     grid-column:span 4;
  }
/**/

/* If 13 is missing, make 12 full width */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12):last-child {
     grid-column:1/-1;
  }
/**/

/* If 11 is missing, make 9 and 10 bigger */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+9):nth-last-child(2),
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+10):last-child {
     grid-column:span 4;
  }
/**/

/* If 10 is missing, make 9 full width */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+9):last-child {
     grid-column:1/-1;
  }
/**/

/* If 8 is missing, make 5 and 7 bigger */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+5),
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+7):last-child {
     grid-column:span 2;
  }
/**/

/* If 7 is missing, make 5 bigger */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+5):nth-last-child(2) {
     grid-column:span 4;
  }
/**/

/* If 6 is missing, make 5 full width */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+5):last-child {
     grid-column:1/-1;
  }
/**/

/* If 4 is missing, make 3 bigger */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+3):last-child {
     grid-column:span 4;
  }
/**/

/* If 2 is missing, make 1 full width */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+1):last-child {
     grid-column:1/-1;
  }
/**/

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 649px) {

/*adjustments to neaten columns if there is an odd number of items (in total, combined for all grids)*/

/* If ending on odd number, make last item full width */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(odd):last-child {
     grid-column:1/-1;
  }
/**/

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are explicitely setting *the position* of each item which is a wrong approach. Instead you need to only define the size and let the browser place the item automatically.

You can also group the elements with the same size together and no need to define a fixed number of rows since you need a repeated pattern. Only the columns need to be defined.

Here is an example where you can easily understand and identify the trick:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* fill all the cells */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* define only the size of each row */
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+1),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+6){
  grid-column:span 4; /* take 4 columns */
  grid-row:span 2; /* take 2 rows */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+2) {
  grid-column:span 4; /* take 4 columns */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+3),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+4),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+5),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+7),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+11),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+13),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+14),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+15){
  border: 1px solid #03C;
  grid-column:span 2; /* take 2 columns */
}
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+7) {
  grid-column:1 / span 2; /* here we need to explicitely set the position to first column + take 2 columns */
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+8) {
  grid-row:span 2; /* take 2 rows */
  grid-column:span 2/-1; /* here also we need an explicit position at the last columns */
  border: 1px solid #f0f;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+9) {
  grid-column:span 3; /* take 3 columns */
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+10) {
  grid-column: span 3 / -1; /* take 3 columns from the end*/
  border: 1px solid green;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  /* we no more need an explicit size so we put all to auto */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(n) {
    grid-row:auto;
    grid-column:auto;
  }
  /**/ 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <!--1st grid-->
  <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 04</div>
  <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 08</div>
  <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 11</div>
  <!--4th row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 12</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 13</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 14</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 15</div>

  <!--2nd grid-->
  <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">2 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 04</div>
  <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">2 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 08</div>
  <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">2 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 11</div>
  <!--4th row-->
  <div class="item">2 - 12</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 13</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 14</div>
  <div class="item">2 - 15</div>

  <!--3rd grid-->
  <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">3 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 04</div>
  <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">3 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 08</div>
  <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">3 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 11</div>
  <!--4th row-->
  <div class="item">3 - 12</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 13</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 14</div>
  <div class="item">3 - 15</div>

  <!--4th grid (incomplete)-->
  <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">4 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 04</div>
  <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">4 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">4 - 07</div>

</div>
```

> is this kind of grid achievable in flexbox?

Yes but you will have a lot of headaches to achieve it and it will be very hacky. CSS grid is the most suitable solution here.

> As a bonus question: there will no doubt not be an even multiple of 15 photos each time (eg ending at the 4th grid in the html below)... is there a way to neaten off the final row of pics and fill the available space in the bottom row?

Yes but you will need to write a specific rule for each case to identify the last item like `nth-child(15n + x):last-child`. This will give you then 15 different rules to be added.

Here is some examples:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* fill all the cells */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* define only the size of each row */
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border:5px solid;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+1),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+6){
  grid-column:span 4; /* take 4 columns */
  grid-row:span 2; /* take 2 rows */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+2) {
  grid-column:span 4; /* take 4 columns */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+3),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+4),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+5),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+7),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+11),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+13),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+14),
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+15){
  border: 1px solid #03C;
  grid-column:span 2; /* take 2 columns */
}
.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+7) {
  grid-column:1 / span 2; /* here we need to explicitely set the position to first column + take 2 columns */
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+8) {
  grid-row:span 2; /* take 2 rows */
  grid-column:span 2/-1; /* here also we need an explicit position at the last columns */
  border: 1px solid #f0f;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+9) {
  grid-column:span 3; /* take 3 columns */
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+10) {
  grid-column: span 3 / -1; /* take 3 columns from the end*/
  border: 1px solid green;
}

/* If 15 is no there we make the last 13 and 14 bigger */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+13):nth-last-child(2),
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+14):last-child {
     grid-column:span 3;
  }
/**/

/* If 15 & 14 no there we make the last 12 and 13 bigger */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12):nth-last-child(2),
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+13):last-child {
     grid-column:span 4;
  }
/**/

/* If 15 & 14 & 13 no there we make the last 12 take all the row */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12):last-child {
     grid-column:1/-1;
  }
/**/

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  /* we no more need an explicit size so we put all to auto */
  .grid .item:nth-of-type(n) {
    grid-row:auto!important;
    grid-column:auto!important;
  }
  /**/ 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <!--1st grid-->
  <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 04</div>
  <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 08</div>
  <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 11</div>
  <!--4th row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 12</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 13</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 14</div>

</div>

<div class="grid">

  <!--1st grid-->
  <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 04</div>
  <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 08</div>
  <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 11</div>
  <!--4th row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 12</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 13</div>

</div>

<div class="grid">

  <!--1st grid-->
  <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 04</div>
  <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 08</div>
  <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 11</div>
  <!--4th row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 12</div>

</div>

<div class="grid">

  <!--1st grid-->
  <!--1st row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 01</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 02</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 03</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 04</div>
  <!--2nd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 05</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 06</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 07</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 08</div>
  <!--3rd row-->
  <div class="item">1 - 09</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 10</div>
  <div class="item">1 - 11</div>

</div>
```

I didn't cover all the cases but you have the idea and you can continue the same way.

Comment: Wow Temani, thanks so much. That works great! Your code was sooooo much better and more efficient than mine. I am new to css grid and have a lot to learn on it. Probably not a good idea for me to start with something so complex (for me) :). Css grid is obviously very powerful to be able to handle a repeating pattern like this. Good to know re flexbox handling this pattern. Thank you very much again for your help.

Comment: Just on this one from the original post ... "As a bonus question: there will no doubt not be an even multiple of 15 photos each time (eg ending at the 4th grid in the html below)... is there a way to neaten off the final row of pics and fill the available space in the bottom row?" ... I am trying `.grid .item:last-of-type { grid-column: auto; grid-row: auto; }` and that is close for `4-07` in this instance in that it aligns it to the RHS of `4-06` but there is a one column gap that doesn't fill. Any tricks for filling the empty space using the last item? Thanks again

Comment: @user3643520 Ok will edit my answer to add some trick to fill empty spaces, but you should note that CSS grid is very bad at this exercise so you will end with a complex code if you want to handle all the cases ;)

Comment: Thanks Temani. Wow, you are truly amazing at the n selectors! I really appreciate you taking the time to work out some of those extra complex scenarios... it is very complex indeed, I had no idea. I followed your lead and created the various selectors, I will try to add so anyone interested can see. Many thanks again and all the best

Comment: Ahhhh. Just checked the html after having issues with my nth selectors and saw you added the extra grid wrappers after every 15. Now I know why it's not working in my mine. In the CMS I won't be able to add the grid wrapper every 15 items. Might leave this as in the photo gallery with the last #13 missing or the last #9 missing the layout breaks (images are using object-fit: cover and the grid rows are bigger in these 2 scenarios for some reason). Thanks again for your help

Comment: `.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12):last-child { grid-column: 1 / -1; }` and `.grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+9):last-child { grid-column: 1 / -1; }` are the ones that break

Comment: ps the height goes funny on all images in the photo grid (they use object-fit: cover) for all of the re-balancing scenarios when the last item is made full width with `grid-column: 1 / -1;` Changing to `grid-column: span 6 etc` does not solve either

Comment: @user3643520 no I am not adding extra wrapper, they are different example of grid to show you the case where you are missing items. I made an example with different grid and each one is missing a specific amount if items, that's why I also added the border to make it clear

Comment: @user3643520 for the height you have to change the `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` to control, use pixel value instead of 1fr for example

Comment: Ahhhhh I see re not adding an extra wrapper... Face palm :)

Comment: Thanks for pixel height idea on all the rows. Wanting to avoid to keep responsive, so just set max-height on the full width 1/-1 row neatening instances eg `.photo-grid .item:nth-of-type(15n+12):last-child { grid-column: 1 / -1; max-height: 250px; }`. This effects the grid ratios (unfortunately) when changing the browser width (the rows / images all seem to use that 250px height, not just the final item), but seems an ok compromise. Many thanks again for your help